# Rewriterule to URL with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's what I'm trying to do...

Redirect from

```
example.com/directory
```

to

```
example.com/?offer=1234
```

I have an .htaccess that I know is being read, but I can't get it to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^directory/?$   /\?offer=1234   [NC]
```

This doesn't redirect at all and keeps you in `/directory`. I know the .htaccess file is being read because if I intentionally mess up the syntax, I get a 500 error.

Comment: Try without \: `RewriteRule   ^directory/?$   /?offer=1234   [NC]`

Comment: @Croises Tried that initially and it didn't work. Found a simple solution that's not quite as pretty, but does the job. `RewriteRule ^directory/?$ http://example.com/?offer=1234`

Comment: it should work with the real file name: `RewriteRule ^directory/?$ index.php?offer=1234 [NC]` or whatever it may be

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple, if not elegant way to solve this:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/?$ http://example.com/?offer=1234
```

Writing out the whole URL isn't ideal, but it does the job.

Comment: I think you should be able to do like this: `RewriteRule ^directory/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/?offer=1234` to avoid adding the complete hostname.